# How to write underscores with spaces between them?

Tags: ios, swift

This is how I define my mask in code:

[image]

and this is how it looks with prefix +48. Why there is no space between characters? Is it something wrong with my character? It doesn't matter what font I use... it is always the same.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It doesnt matter what font I use...

Clearly you haven't tried [every font](http://iosfonts.com). If you type in some underscores in that website, you will find exactly which fonts have underscores that are separated, and which don't. For example, `DevanagariSangamMN` is a font that does have separated underscores.

```
let view = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40))
view.font = UIFont(name: "DevanagariSangamMN", size: 16)
view.text = "___ ___ ___"
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

[image]

Of course, the more "proper" way of doing this is to adjust the character spacing, by giving it the characters a positive [*kern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) value.

That looks like a `UITextField`, so you can set its `defaultTextAttributes`:

```
yourTextField.defaultTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.kern: 2
]
```